# How can I use string in AddHandler?

Tags: vb.net

I have a situation where I am creating radiobutton dynamically and I need to assign a handler on CheckedChanged. Here I don't have any specific function or procedure. So I wrote this statement:

```
 AddHandler rb.CheckedChanged, AddressOf rb.Tag
```

But it gives error. How can I achieve this?

EDITED:

Actually I am writing a DLL for other programmers in the company. So they can design a particular form at run time. For now I have a procedure which creates all the controls. So for now if they want to create a radio button they call the procedure

```
AddRadioButton(Text as string, Checked as boolean)
```

Now on request,I want to add another parameter in this where they can give Procedure name as string and I can add handler to address of ProcedureName. SO now procedure will become like this

```
AddRadioButton(Text as string, Checked as boolean, OnCheckedProcedure as string)
```

And in my code I will use

```
AddHandler rb.CheckedChanged, AddressOf OnCheckedProcedure
```

Comment: What do you expect it to **do** with this string when the checked status is changed?

Answer (score 1):

The method you add has a handler has to have the same parameters as the event you are trying to handle.  As far as the RadioButton, here is what the handler might look like for what you are trying to do:

```
Private Sub CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim tempRB As RadioButton= CType(sender, RadioButton)

    tempRB.Tag = tempRB.Checked.ToString

End Sub
```

Then you can add your handler like this:

```
        AddHandler rb.CheckedChanged, AddressOf CheckedChanged
```